# EC2へのSSH接続ができない

Tags: linux, ssh, amazon-ec2

AWSにてVPCとセキュリティグループ、EC2を作成しました。
サブネットを割り当て自分のターミナルにてSSH接続を試みましたがSSH接続ができない状況です。

実行コマンド：

```
> ssh -i xxx.pem ec2-user@Elasticipアドレス
```

エラー結果は以下になります。

```
ec2-user@Elasticipアドレス: Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).
```

pemキーは自分のダウンロードフォルダ内に存在しており、権限は以下です

```
-rw-------@ 　　xxx.pem
```

また、エラーの詳細を知るために `ssh -vvv` を実行した結果は下記になります。

```
penSSH_8.1p1, LibreSSL 2.7.3
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/xxx/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 47: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 1qaz2wsx.pem port 22.
ssh: Could not resolve hostname xxx.pem: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
```

名前解決ができていないと思うのですが、具体的にどこを修正すればいいかわかりません。
どなたか教えていただけないでしょうか。

Comment: ご呈示のエラーメッセージは`ssh -i xxx.pem ec2-user@Elasticip`したときのものですか？エラーの内容と実行コマンドに乖離があるよに見受けられます。
`ssh: Could not resolve hostname xxx.pem: nodename nor servname` ssh xxx.pem としていませんか？ 実行されたコマンドではホスト名をxxx.pemだと思われていませんか？また、このエラーメッセージはコピペではなく「手打ち」でしょうか。

Comment: ssh -i xxx.pem ec2-user@Elasticipをしたときに下記エラーメッセージが表示されました。ec2-user@Elasticipアドレス: Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic). エラーメッセージはコピペになります。

Comment: [EC2 インスタンスにアクセスする際の「Permission denied (Publickey)」または「Authentication failed, Permission denied」エラーのトラブルシューティング](https://aws.amazon.com/jp/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ec2-linux-fix-permission-denied-errors/)

Answer (score -1):

Elasticの`/etc/ssh/sshd_config`を編集して、sshdを再起動してみてください。

```
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key
PubkeyAuthentication yes
```